# Cerrar sesión en una aplicación de Azure Active Directory desde una aplicación WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, azure

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación de escritorio en WPF con C#, la cual se conecta a una aplicación de Azure AD, al momento de intenta cerrar sesión con la documentación oficial solo borra la cache pero no cierra sesión de la aplicación, por eso al intentar volver conectarme ya me aparece como conectado.
[image: ejemplo de inicio de sesión, pero aparece como si siguiera conectado]

[image: El código que uso para cerrar sesión es el siguiente]

Answer (score 0):

Con las siguiente correcciones a mi código puedo mandar llamar un navegador para cerrar sesión de una manera definitiva.

```
private async void SignOutButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var accounts = await App.PublicClientApp.GetAccountsAsync();
            if (accounts.Any())
            {
                try
                {

                    await App.PublicClientApp.RemoveAsync(accounts.FirstOrDefault());
                    NavigationWindow window = new NavigationWindow();
                    window.Source = new Uri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/logout");
                    window.Show();
                    this.ResultText.Text = "User has signed-out";
                    this.CallGraphButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    this.SignOutButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                }
                catch (MsalException ex)
                {
                    ResultText.Text = $"Error signing-out user: {ex.Message}";
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Otra alternativa seria cambiar el codigo de adquerir el token y poner que sea un login forzado.

```
  try
                {
                    authResult = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
                        .WithPrompt(Prompt.ForceLogin) 
                        .ExecuteAsync();
                }
                catch (MsalException msalex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Error Acquiring Token:{System.Environment.NewLine}{msalex}");
                }
```